# EXPEDI - Expedition Spoj Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, heap

**EXPEDI - Expedition**

A group of cows grabbed a truck and ventured on an expedition deep into the jungle. Being rather poor drivers, the cows unfortunately managed to run over a rock and puncture the truck's fuel tank. The truck now leaks one unit of fuel every unit of distance it travels.

To repair the truck, the cows need to drive to the nearest town (no more than 1,000,000 units distant) down a long, winding road. On this road, between the town and the current location of the truck, there are N (1 <= N <= 10,000) fuel stops where the cows can stop to acquire additional fuel (1..100 units at each stop).

The jungle is a dangerous place for humans and is especially dangerous for cows. Therefore, the cows want to make the minimum possible number of stops for fuel on the way to the town. Fortunately, the capacity of the fuel tank on their truck is so large that there is effectively no limit to the amount of fuel it can hold. The truck is currently L units away from the town and has P units of fuel (1 <= P <= 1,000,000).

Determine the minimum number of stops needed to reach the town, or if the cows cannot reach the town at all.

Input
The first line of the input contains an integer t representing the number of test cases. Then t test cases follow. Each test case has the follwing form:

Line 1: A single integer, N
Lines 2..N+1: Each line contains two space-separated integers describing a fuel stop: The first integer is the distance from the town to the stop; the second is the amount of fuel available at that stop.
Line N+2: Two space-separated integers, L and P
Output
For each test case, output a single integer giving the minimum number of fuel stops necessary to reach the town. If it is not possible to reach the town, output -1.

**Example**

```
Input:
1
4
4 4
5 2
11 5
15 10
25 10

Output:
2

Input details
The truck is 25 units away from the town; the truck has 10 units
of fuel.  Along the road, there are 4 fuel stops at distances 4,
5, 11, and 15 from the town (so these are initially at distances
21, 20, 14, and 10 from the truck).  These fuel stops can supply
up to 4, 2, 5, and 10 units of fuel, respectively.

Output details:
Drive 10 units, stop to acquire 10 more units of fuel, drive 4 more
units, stop to acquire 5 more units of fuel, then drive to the town.
```

**My code**

```
import heapq

class FuelPump:
    def __init__(self,dist,fuel,visited = False):
        self.dist = dist
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.visited = visited


    def __lt__(self,otherObject):
        return self.fuel > otherObject.fuel

# <- TAKING INPUTS HERE->
test_cases = int(input())
for _ in range(test_cases):
    n = int(input())
    fuelPumps = []
    for i in range(n):
        dist,fuel = map(int,input().split())
        fuelPumps.append([dist,fuel])
    totalDist, initialFuel = map(int,input().split())

    pumps = []
    for i in range(len(fuelPumps)):
        currFuel = fuelPumps[i][1]
        distFromTown = fuelPumps[i][0]
        currDist = totalDist - distFromTown
        currObj = FuelPump(currDist,currFuel)
        pumps.append(currObj)

    # pumps = sorted(pumps)
    # for pump in pumps:
    #     print("dist =",pump.dist," fuel =",pump.fuel)
    res = 0

    # remainingDist = totalDist
    currRange = initialFuel
    fuelTank = initialFuel
    remainingDist = totalDist
    visited = set()
    prevPumpDist = 0

    while totalDist > currRange:
        maxHeap = []

        for pump in pumps:
            if pump.dist <= currRange and pump.dist not in visited:
                # print(pump.dist,pump.fuel)
                heapq.heappush(maxHeap,pump)


        if len(maxHeap) == 0:
            res = -1
            break

        top = maxHeap[0]
        visited.add(top.dist)
        distTravelled = top.dist - prevPumpDist

        fuelTank -= distTravelled
        fuelTank += top.fuel

        res += 1
        currRange = fuelTank + top.dist

        for pump in pumps:
            if pump.dist <= top.dist:
                visited.add(pump.dist)
        prevPumpDist = top.dist
        # print("selected fuel pump dist from start = ",top.dist," fuel picked up =",top.fuel,"fuelTank =",fuelTank," currRange =",currRange," distTravelled =",distTravelled," visited =",visited)

    print(res)
```

**My approach**
We do the following until the currRange is greater equal to the total distance:

We append all the gas stations in the current range to our maxHeap and then select the one with highest fuel and which was not visited (or we already drove by it).

If their no gas station within the currRange then we break and print -1.

Then we calculate the distance between the previous selected gas station and current station and we subtract that distance from our fuel tank.

We then add the fuel from current station to our fuelTank. We mark the current gas station as visited and also the stations we drove by.

Increment the res variable by 1

**My doubt**
The code works perfectly for given TC however it shows wrong answer when i submit it. Is my logic wrong?

Comment: So the truck leaks 1 unit of fuel per unit of distance. How much does it *consume* for driving one unit of distance?

Comment: Nothing is written about that so lets assume that the truck travels by leaking the fuel. Also, please have a look https://www.spoj.com/problems/EXPEDI/ i might have missed reading about that.

Comment: "select the one with highest fuel and which was not visited (or we already drove by it)" Why can't you select a station that you've driven by? That's probably the main reason behind the WA verdict

Comment: Because after you select a gas station and now you want to select a station you already drove by, you'll have to start driving back to it and then again towards the town. That sounds overcomplicated and wrong.

Comment: @ShubhamPrashar that's incorrect. You're planning a route when you have the station data BEFOREHAND. You're simulating the route, so you can pick the station with highest fuel that we've crossed in our path.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I'm completely agreeing with you Abhinav, to be very honest I was confused about the same. I commented the lines where i was adding old stations to the visited set and now the judge shows TLE. What do you think the solution is correct?

Comment: Your approach is mostly correct. As you pass a station, add it to the heap. When you need fuel, pop the heap and proceed similarly.